# sendMessage for HWND_BROADCAST is not working

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I am trying to send message to from1 from fromMain, I use findwindow to find handle of form1 and sendMessage, it works perfectly. But I use sendMessage to broadcast the message, it is not working at all. Any one please help me find out what is wrong?

```
    Public Const WM_MyMsg As Integer = &H8001
    Public Const HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = &HFFFF&


    Dim hnwd As Integer = CInt(FindWindow(vbNullString, "form1"))
    SendMessage(hnwd, WM_MyMsg, 0, 0) 'works perfectly, form1 get the msg


    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_MyMsg, 0, 0) 'not working at all, form1 doesn't have any response
```

Comment: You are attempting to send this message to all top level windows on the current desktop. You absolutely do not want to do that.

Comment: I know it might be some risk, but I just want to know why this code is not working. Thanks!

Comment: Might be some risk?!! That's stating it lightly! The system is protecting poor defenceless applications from abuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to broadcast to all top-level windows a custom message in the `WM_APP` range. Such messages are private within applications and the system knows that is invalid to broadcast them, and stops you doing so. It decides to do this to avoid poorly designed applications causing instabilities in other applications.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) is quite clear on how you can broadcast custom messages:

> Applications that need to communicate using HWND_BROADCAST should use the RegisterWindowMessage function to obtain a unique message for inter-application communication.